# QR De/Encoder SIGABRT error (switching between de/encoder)

Tags: ios, xcode, qr-code, tabbar, zbar-sdk

hey guys i have to make an app for my school project which includes reading an creating of QR Codes...

No Problem so far. I started with making a tap bar application so that you can switch between the two settings.
I'm using the ZBarSDK to read the Codes and that works so far...
for creating the codes i am using the kuapay-iOS-QR-Code-Generator and that worke also...

but if i combine them in my app i get the SIGABRT error after switching between the views :/

i hope you can help me i uploaded the whole project, so that everybody can see the problem directly!

Link: http://www.mediafire.com/?01acxgitv27uj9n

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the FAQ so you can get higher quality answers to your questions.

Please provide some information as to exactly what you want, what you have tried so far, and what isn't working. People here on SO normally frown upon questions that ask the answers to provide any source code if available without showing any effort in the question. This could cause your question to be down-voted. Just submitting 140 MB of code anywhere is not welcome.

Comment: i leave this in mind so i know what to do next time...
and i had to submit the whole file because i don't know where the problem could be...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, have you disabled the armv7s architecture in your build settings? Also, have you made sure to connect all your outlets to appropriately declared properties? I'm fairly new too, and I would have made this a comment instead of an answer, but it seems I don't have enough rep to do so/ can't find the link to comment.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer i already tried to change the architecture but it didn't work :/ i have also every property, outlet, action... connected and the problem still occurs 
i think the two sdk's just can't work together (the kuapay generator is based of a .mm file and the zbarsdk not)

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. I looked over your code, and the only other advice I can offer is to make sure you made your tabs from scratch. I tried using the tabs that were included in the default tabbed app template and I could never get it to work. I started from scratch and a lot of problems went away.